Requesting Token with ClientID of User-Assigned Managed Identity as scope
I want to request a token using the clientID of a user-assigned managed identity as the scope, so that the token I receive has the clientID as its audience.
To achieve this, I used the following code in C#:
var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
{
ManagedIdentityClientId = clientID
});
var token = await credential.GetTokenAsync(new TokenRequestContext(new[]
{ $"{clientID}/.default" }) { });

This code is running in an Azure App Service that has the user-assigned managed identity assigned to it.
My problem is that this process already worked for me and I received the token in the way I need. Unfortunately this suddenly stopped working without me changing anything neither in the code nor in my Azure configuration. I now get the following error:

ManagedIdentityCredential authentication failed: Service request failed. Status: 500 (Internal Server Error) Content: {"statusCode":500,"message":"An unexpected error occured while fetching the AAD Token."

I am still able to request a token when using a different scope. What could cause this issue? Thanks for your help.

Were you able to resolve this? We have an open support ticket with Microsoft on this topic.
It seems like there has been a recent change (validation?) when requesting a token. In our Azure AD managed identity sign in logs we also see this :
Can not use Managed Service Identity (MSI) as audience in token as it is unsupported. MSI should not be set as audience as it does not accept tokens.

One question I have, what is the token ultimately used for? There are overloads of a lot of Azure resources in the SDK that accept the DefaultAzureCredential as a param, so you don't have to request a token explicitly.


ManagedIdentityCredential authentication failed: Service request failed. Status: 500 (Internal Server Error) Content: {"statusCode":500,"message":"An unexpected error occurred while fetching the AAD Token."

I got the same error when I tried to fetch token using the same code.
string clientID = "<Azure_CLIENT_ID>";
var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
{
    ManagedIdentityClientId = clientID
});
var token = credential.GetTokenAsync(new TokenRequestContext(new[]
{ $"{clientID}/.default" })
{ });

To resolve the error, I have added below environment variables in the App Service Configuration:
AZURE_CLIENT_ID
AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET
AZURE_TENANT_ID


Enabled User Managed Identity.
Able to fetch the token using User-Managed Identity.



What is the client secret though if it is managed identity? The point of using managed identity is so you don't use secrets, indeed you can't
